# angularjs $cookiestore erratic behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, cookies

I have been using $cookieStore for saving cookies in my angularjs application. Everywhere it is working fine till i found this one issue.
On one page I have been receiving data from server saving it in a cookie name company and redirecting to another route using $location.path
On the very next page when I am using that cookie to get data, it is returning the old cookie data.
I am getting this issue only in chrome after every alternative time i.e. for once it works fine but next time it doesn't get any data. However i tried it many times on firefox it is working absolutely fine. I not able to understand why is this happening in chrome and not in some other browser.

Here is the code :-

Saving data in cookie

```
$cookieStore.put('company',{'company_id':company.company_id, 'funding_id':company.funding_id, 'invest_amount':amount_to_send,'company_error':company.company_name, 'progress_id':progress_id});

console.log($cookieStore.get('company')); //returning correct data
```

Here i retrieve data in next function called on another route

```
console.log($cookieStore.get('company')); //returning wrong data
```

Both functions are defined in same controller.

Comment: I believe $cookiestore uses an asynchronous $watch, that could be throwing off your stuff.

Comment: I have the same problem, when I set a cookie value and then use $location.url()

Comment: I removed angular cookieStore and used jquery cookies instead, everything went perfect. I guess there is some issue with cookieStore. If you keep changing data after every few seconds it sours the deal.